# How to add text-highlight in asmoday74\ckeditor5\EditorClassic in Yii Framework?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-components

I'd like to add to my EditorClassic Yii component the possibility of highlighting text with colors.
This is the current component, it has by default options such as bold, italic, underline etc.

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'description', ['options' => [

                ]])->widget(EditorClassic::className(), [
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'language' => 'fr',
                    ]
            ]) ?>
```

I tried adding inside `clientOptions[]` :

```
'toolbar' => [
        ['TextColor'],
```

but didn't work.